# What is the correct way to exit RI?

Tags: ruby, ri

What is the right combination for exit RI on Ubuntu(13.04)?

For example, the following line:

```
ri GC::enable
```

gives me:

[image]

pressing the following commands do nothing: PAUSE/BREAK, Home, End, Ctrl+Shift+D

The only thing that exist is *ctrl+c* but it throws errors like this:

> from
>   /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:774:in
>   `display_class'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:800:in`
>   display_name'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:827:in
>   `block in display_names'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:824:in`
>   each'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:824:in
>   `display_names'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:1361:in`
>   run'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/ri/driver.rb:356:in
>   `run'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/bin/ri:12:in`
>   '
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ri:23:in `load'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ri:23:in`'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in
>   `eval'
>           from /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`
>   '

and something more, even it seems the RI has been stopped, but pressing any of the keys gives me again this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press `q`.

`ri` pipes the output through what's called a pager. The pager on most systems is a program that is named either `more` or `less`. See the manpages for those commands for more information (`man more` or `man less`).

You can set your pager through the environment variable `PAGER` in the shell. For example on my machine in bash:

```
> echo $PAGER
/usr/bin/less
```

Answer (score 2):

Just press `q`.

It's the same as exiting man pages.

Answer (score 2):

```
▶ ri -i

Enter the method name you want to look up.
You can use tab to autocomplete.
Enter a blank line to exit.

>>
```

Like it says.

You can also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to indicate end of input from your keyboard device if you used `ri -i` for interactive mode.

Now if it opened up your pager, then <kbd>q</kbd> may work (if it is `less`, for example) otherwise see the `man`ual for your pager.